# How to disable clientside click of a link button or an image button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have an image button and link button which have client click events.
I want to disable client click of these buttons using jquery or javascript function
Finding the button and attaching

```
$("#linkBtn").disable()
```

to them is disabling the server click but not the client click. Please help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: anchor link? input button? button element?

Comment: You want this on client side?You want this functionality at run time or static ?

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent click event by simply calling `preventDefault` of event or by `return false`;

```
$("#linkBtn").click(function(e){

   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
})
```

Comment: return false;
this will avoid click from making a postback. But already by default my link button has an inline 'return false;' in it. i want it to be unclickable.

Comment: you can use <a href="javascript: void(0)">I am a useless link</a> to disable link.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Client Side

```
 YourControl.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled= 'disabled' ");
```

You can also use

```
OnClientClick = "return false";
```

Comment: Avoid sending the form click on this control

Comment: Sarcasm is often hard to spot on the internet - my bad.  I believe you mean return, not retrun?

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are two possibilities:

1.)You want static disable for client click :

for this case you can use

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="return false;">Open the Glossary</a>.
 <img onclick = "return false;" alt="test" src="1.jpg"/>
```

OR

2.) You want this at runtime :

```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function test() {
        //your logic
        return false;
    }
</script>
 <a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="return test();">Open the Glossary</a>.
 <img onclick = "return test();" alt="test" src="1.jpg"/>
```